# Selecting more than one random item in a list of cards

Tags: python, random

I want to have two separate random selections from the same list. Is there any way to do this that doesn't include making separate lists?

```
import random


cards = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'King','Queen','Jack']
cards = random.choice(cards)

suits = ['Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Spades', 'Diamonds']
suits = random.choice(suits)

first_card = ("your first card is the {} of {}") .format(cards,suits)
second_card = ("your second card is the {} of {}") .format(cards,suits)

print first_card
print second_card
```

#### Output

```
your first card is the 10 of Spades
your second card is the 10 of Spades
```

I want the output to be the same but the last card dealt is different from the first; two separate cards

Comment: What would you like to see as an output?

Comment: Why don't you make one large random selection, and then split that output into two?

Comment: Do you want them to be unique? Use random.sample. Can they be the same? Use random.choice twice on the same list.

Comment: If you want to choose two different categories (like `cards` and `suits` - their very meanings are different), you can't just do `random.choice(cards + suits)` because the probabilities of any item to be chosen is the same as that of any other item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beforehand, generate all cards from figures and suits, by example with a list-comprehension. Then use `random.sample` to pick two random cards.

```
import random

figures = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack']
suits = ['Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Spades', 'Diamonds']

cards = [(figure, suit) for figure in figures for suit in suits]

print(random.sample(cards, 2)) # [(5, 'Hearts'), (7, 'Diamonds')]
```

Although, I recommend you do not mix integers and strings to define your figures as this may lead to some confusion. I recommend you assign integers `11`, `12` and `13` to `Jack`, `Queen` and `King` respectively.

Comment: +1. Also, `(cards[i // 4], suits[i % 4]) for i in random.sample(range(n_cards), n_cards)` avoids an explicit product in memory. Useful for especially large values of 52.

Answer (score 0):

you can use itertools to generate all combination and then shuffle the list and take two , I have designed function for n_samples you can select n no of samples:

```
import random
import itertools

cards = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'King','Queen','Jack']


suits = ['Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Spades', 'Diamonds']

def n_random(list_1,list_2,no_of_samples):
    all_possible=[i for i in itertools.product(list_1,list_2)]
    if no_of_samples>len(all_possible):
        return 'Wrong choice'
    else:
        random.shuffle(all_possible)
        return all_possible[:2]

print(n_random(cards,suits,2))
```

output:

```
[(3, 'Diamonds'), (2, 'Spades')]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `random.sample`.

`random.sample(population, k)`:

Return a `k` length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set.

```
import random

cards = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'King','Queen','Jack']
chosen_cards = random.sample(cards,2)

suits = ['Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Spades', 'Diamonds']
chosen_suits = random.sample(suits,2)

first_card = ("your first card is the {} of {}") .format(chosen_cards[0],chosen_suits[0])
second_card = ("your second card is the {} of {}") .format(chosen_cards[1],chosen_suits[1])

print(first_card)
print(second_card)
```

Comment: This will not allow for every possible combination of cards to be selected.  For example, you could never select both the `2 of hearts` and the `2 of spades`.

Answer (score -3):

This guarantees a different card every time:

```
from random import randint
cards = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'King','Queen','Jack']
first_card = cards[randint(0, len(cards)-1)]
second_card = cards[randint(0, len(cards)-1)]
while second_card == first_card:
   second_card = cards[randint(0, len(cards)-1)]
print first_card
print second_card
```

Comment: This would allow them to pick the same card twice.  Also, when answering, code-only answers are better with explanation!

Comment: @chrisz, what's wrong with picking the same card twice? Nowhere in the question is it said that the choices must be unique.

Comment: This will allow a different card every time! try to test the code before commenting

Comment: This doesn't *guarantee* a different card every time.  Also, @ForceBru "I want to have two separate random selections occur from the same list."

Comment: @chrisz, yes, it definitely doesn't guarantee that. Again, nothing is said about the uniqueness of the selections. That they are _separate_  means that they're independent.

Comment: @ForceBru "last card dealt is different from the first" couldn't be more clear